.npy to .aedat4 to view videos from event camera (davis346)
Got a dataset recorded from davis346, which is an event-based camera from iniVation. But every file in the dataset ends with .npy. I want to convert them to aedat4 or some other formats for visualizing, viewing purposes.
I tried to search for some existing python libraries but it seems there isn't one

What steps have you taken so far?
